# React typescript test on enzyme doesn't simulate click

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to simulate a click on a button but the test always fails and I have no idea why. It seems that enzyme can't select the DOM element to trigger a click on it, because the calls are always 0. I am using enzyme 3.7.0 and jest 23.6.0

**Button.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './button.scss';

export interface IButton {
  value: string;
  onClick: () => void;
}

class Button extends React.Component<IButton, {}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Button">
        <button id="btn" onClick={this.props.onClick} className="Button__btn" type="button">
          {this.props.value}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Button;
```

**Button.test.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Button  from './Button';

test.only('Button test', () => {
  const myMock = jest.fn();

  const mockedButton = shallow(<Button value="testvalue" onClick={() => myMock} />);
  console.log(mockedButton.debug());

  // Interaction demo
  expect(mockedButton.text()).toEqual('testvalue');

  mockedButton.find('button').simulate('click');
  mockedButton.find('.Button__btn').simulate('click');
  mockedButton.find('button.Button__btn').simulate('click');
  expect(myMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(0); // !! Should be 3 ?

  // Snapshot demo
  expect(mockedButton).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

However, the snapshot generated could allow me to select the right element (button)

```
exports[`Button test 1`] = `
<div
  className="Button"
>
  <button
    className="Button__btn"
    onClick={[Function]}
  >
    testvalue
  </button>
</div>
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is this part:

```
onClick={() => myMock}
```

Here you describe click handler that returns your mock instead of calling it. It should be `onClick={() => myMock()}` or better just `onClick={myMock}`

instead. There React will call your `myMock` on `.simulate('click')`